# Using Datatables with ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'd like use Datatables jquery plug-in with ASP.NET. What is the best way to generate the HTML table needed?

Comment: webforms or mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax, there are plenty of code examples on the Datatables web site

https://datatables.net/examples/

This is how I got started using Datatables.